# MongoEngine: Array Positional Projection in Embedded document

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to reproduce the following query in python using MongoEngine without much success.

Original source for data and query:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/#prj._S_

The query basically returns the first element matched in the embedded document and not the whole embedded document itself.

My code:

```
from mongoengine import *
connect('test')


class Student(Document):
    semester = IntField()
    grades = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Grade'))


class Grade(EmbeddedDocument):
    value = FloatField()

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.value

student_1 = Student(semester=1, grades=[Grade(value=70), Grade(value=87), Grade(value=90)]).save()
student_2 = Student(semester=1, grades=[Grade(value=90), Grade(value=88), Grade(value=92)]).save()

result = Student.objects(semester=1, grades__value__gte=85).only("grades.$")

for r in result:
    print r.grades
```

When I do this, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_me_so.py", line 21, in <module>
    result = Student.objects(semester=1, grades__value__gte=85).only("grades.$")
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 1225, in only
    return self.fields(**fields)
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 1271, in fields
    fields = self._fields_to_dbfields(fields)
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 1289, in _fields_to_dbfields
    field = ".".join(f.db_field for f in QuerySet._lookup_field(self._document, field.split('.')))
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset.py", line 1289, in <genexpr>
    field = ".".join(f.db_field for f in QuerySet._lookup_field(self._document, field.split('.')))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'db_field'
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of mongoengine's syntax, but I think you don't need the "only" bit.

The $ positional indicator usually grabs relevant values from the array, and it sounds like it will be involved.

Answer (score 0):

The [positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/) is for updating the first element inside an array that matches your query.

The query language is about finding documents and currently you cannot filter an array inside a document.  You can slice and return a subset of the array, but not only return a matched subset.

So in this case you'd have to filter the grades in python and as part of the loop.

An alternative strategy might be to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation/) to $unwind the array and $match and then rebuild the grades array - but that is not built into mongoengine at this time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But the mongodb [doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/positional/) states that the positional operator is for selecting data as well as updating data. I ended up doing this query in mongodb directly.